# Type defined inside class not recognized as return type of method in implementation

Tags: c++

I am surprised why a self-defined type with `using` inside a class is not recognized when I use it as the return value of a method of that same class.

In this example `Pair` is recognized well in the class definition but not in the implementation of `createPair()`:

```
#include <utility>

class A
{
public:
    using Pair = std::pair<int, int>;
    Pair createPair();
};


Pair A::createPair()
{
    return {0, 0};
}
```

The error shown is:

```
error: ‘Pair’ does not name a type
      | Pair A::createPair()
      | ^~~~
```

Why? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Replace it with `A::Pair`

Comment: @AnoopRana That's right! I didn't realize `Pair` was not anymore in `A`'s scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that to use the alias `Pair` we have to be in the scope of the class `A` which we can do by qualifying `Pair` with `A` using the scope resolution operator `::` as shown below:

```
//--vvv----------------------->note the A:: part
    A::Pair A::createPair()
    {
        return {0, 0};
    }
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sDSBozeZQufD0HBj)

Answer (score 0):

Besides `A::Pair` solution of [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289912/941531), it is possible to do fancy stuff like following to avoid specifying `A::`:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/Gz9d7333z)

```cpp
auto A::createPair() -> Pair
{
    return {0, 0};
}
```